# Reference of array inside another array (not an item of the other array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

This is probably a dumb question but whatever.

If have two arrays like this:

```
let a = [0,1,2];
let b = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
```

Is it possible that I can make changes in one happen in the other array as if they are the same place in memory but different lengths like you could in C? (in javascript)

What i want:

```
a[0] = 1;
console.log(b);
//[1,1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(a);
//[1,1,2];
```

Comment: javascript does not share same memory for different data. the pointer approach does not works. instead, you could use a `proxy` and use the property accessor for both arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz  omg I didnt even know proxy existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with plain arrays (unless using getters/setters or proxies to copy the values). However, a shared memory like in C is possible with [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) and their [`subarray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) method:

```js
const b = Uint8Array.from([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const a = b.subarray(0, 3);
console.log(a, b);
a[0] = 1;
console.log(a, b);
```

The downside (?) is that you can store only integers in the array, not objects or strings.